# Laravel Backpack devtools add-on not working?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm having an issue with devtools.

I just did a clean install of Laravel followed by new backpack install. During the install when I was prompted to install paid add-ons, I went to the backpack site and purchased "backpack pro" and "devtools". Went back to installer and installed both add-ons. Everything worked as expected with no errors.

Then went to http://project.test/admin. Registered an admin account. Logged in. Then went to http://project.test/admin/devtools. App/Models/User is shown on the models screen so I clicked the generate CRUD button. It seemed like it was doing something, but I didn't see anything change.

Now on the Models screen, the "Generate button" under actions is disabled and the disabled class is present on the button in the inspector. The CRUDs link in the top navbar links to nothing (a href="#").

So now I click the "Generate All CRUDs button". It pops up the green notification which displays "CRUD generated for: " nothing, it doesn't show a CRUD name.

When I click the "See files" button on the model, it shows a list of all the files it created except the Route link and the Menu link are disabled.

I'm not sure if missing something - what do I do now?

NEW INFO

I finally found an error. Creating a new model with migration works. However, when trying to generate a CRUD for any model, I get this error:

str_repeat(): Argument #2 ($times) must be greater than or equal to 0

It's happening in the middleware:
App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin
in the handle function on line 66. Line 66 is: return $next($request);

Comment: Thank you for submitting this! We weren't aware of this - but this was a HUGE bug in a DevTools dependency. We've just pushed the fix, so a `composer update` should fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've just create a new Laravel app and followed the steps to add the PRO and Devtools repo.

I did the same as you did, opened the "Models" and saw only `User`. I made sure I deleted the user migration before as you said that Models without migration wouldn't work.

I clicked `Generate CRUD`, and got the green notifications.
This is what I get when I click on `See Files`

https://prnt.sc/t7kbQme68yVM

Route and Menu are disabled because it's a feature we are still working on, nothing that impacts the application.

If your issue persist please open a issue report on https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/devtools-issues

**UPDATE**: We found a situation where that `str_repeat` could trigger, we are working on it and will patch it ASAP. I will let you know here when we do it

**UPDATE 2**: It was fixed. Thanks for the report!

Cheers